# How To Set Default Layout For ASP Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am assuming there is a way to set a default layout to use if one is not selected, but I cant seem to find any documentation on it.

From the controller, if I call `return View()` it returns the page without any of the html from the layout. If i return the view as follows, the layout shows up fine.

```
return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_PublicLayout.cshtml");
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to set the default variable for the layout so i don't have to specify it every time for every view.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the views folder locate or create file `_ViewStart.cshtml` and inside you can define:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

where `_Layout.cshtml` is your default layout.